# Problem with breaking out Jquery each loop?

Tags: jquery, loops, break, out, each

I have some html element like these:

```
 <table id="myTable"></table>

    <select name="mySelect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="addToTable()">Add new</a>

    <script>
    addToTable = function() {
      var selected = $("select[name*='mySelect'] option:selected").val();
      $('#myTable').find('tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id')==selected) { 
          alert('Record has already existed!'); return false;
        }
        else $('#myTable').append('<tr id="'+selected+'"><td>'+selected+'</td></tr>');
      });
    }
    </script>
```

The problem was: when I added two records (rows) with the same id, it alerted the message but kept appending the new row instead of breaking out the loop. What was I wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you were wrong adding elements with the same IDs

Comment: What he said ^. You can NOT have the same ID="...." tag more than once on a page. If you want to do something like that, you should put it in a custom attribute, or in class.

Comment: I know. Thats why I need to check the element ID. If the ID has already existed, do nothing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just check if ($("#" + selected) != undefined) {// element already exists, do nothing} then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing:

```
for every existing row R
  if R.id == newRow.id
    alert
    break
  else
    add newRow
```

This will add the newRow for each row that comes before an existing row with that id. With rows [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and adding a row 9 will add that row 8 times before alerting "already exists".

What you mean to do is:

```
exists = false
for every existing row R
  if R.id == newRow.id
    existing = true
    alert
    break

if !exists
  add newRow
```

Equivalent in JS:

```
addToTable = function() {
  var selected = $("select[name*='mySelect'] option:selected").val();
  var exists = false;
  $('#myTable').find('tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id')==selected) { 
      alert('Record has already existed!');
      exists = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if(!exists) {
    $('#favourite_hotels_table').append('<tr id="'+selected+'"><td>'+selected+'</td></tr>');
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's an idea to use .data() to store information about the content of that table. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/9ET3h/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe something wring with the else, and if you try like this ?

```
addToTable = function() {
    var selected = $("select[name*='mySelect'] option:selected").val();
    $('#myTable').find('tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == selected) {
            alert('Record has already existed!');
            return false;
        } else {
          $('#favourite_hotels_table').append('<tr id="' + selected + '"><td>' + selected + '</td></tr>');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That was my typo mistake. "#myTable" instead of "#favourite_hotels_table". :D. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/gj9eN/1/, but your code seems incorrect.

When there are no rows in the table to start with, the .each() on tr will never execute. Please provide more code to verify this?

Doesn't this work better (and shorter):

```
addToTable = function() {
    var selected = $("select[name*='mySelect'] option:selected").val();

    if ($("#" + selected) == undefined) {
        $('#myTable').append('<tr id="'+selected+'"><td>'+selected+'</td></tr>');
    } else {
        alert('Record already exists!');
    }
}
```